# Entity Framework and Application Intent parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, synonym

I have a stored proc that uses a synonym to pull data from another SQL Server 2016 database.

This is the connection string that EF is using:

```
<add name="ConnectionString_CSAdminEF_RO" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;initial catalog=csadmin;user=tcrpAdminTool;password=XXXX;applicationintent=readonly" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It throws this error:

*The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MYSERVER.CORP.COMPANY.COM" does not contain the table "otherserver"."dbo"."mysynonym"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.*

When I try it in ADO.NET it throws this error:

*Procedure usp_get_Data has no parameters and arguments were supplied.*

Here is the synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[mysynonym] FOR [OTHERSERVER.CORP.COMPANY.COM].[mydb].[dbo].[eDocsEntity]
```

The problem only started when I added applicationintent=readonly. This additional parameter works fine when no parameter is involved.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I've seen nothing in the forums about it

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 0):

From our DBA:

I was working on a linked server on primary not realizing that when you read only route to secondary you have to check the secondary servers linked server and in secondary which is a DMS primary they are using a server which did not have read rights to the database referenced by the synonym

I gave it read permissions and that's it